# new project from an old project on objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, filenames

I have an old project, with a large amount of files, which I want to use as the base for a new project.

I need to change workspace, project paths and some files names.

I did some of it, but still get files on old paths especially in target compile source.

What are the steps I need to do to convert to a new project, with new name?

Answer (score 0):

You can add files from existing files. In Xcode, File->Add files to "your project name"...

you select the existing files, then check the "Copy items into destination group's folder".

New files are going to create in your new project. If you want to rename files, you can change in navigation area.

Comment: I have all the files, how would adding help? this is not answering the question